# Как динамически заполнять данными ViewTable? Данные не всегда одинаковые

Tags: java, javafx

Есть ViewTable, так же есть MySQL сервер.
Как сделать чтобы при выборе таблице, ViewTable заполнялась. 
PS Данные различные

Comment: почитайте [тут](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part2/) про tableView

Comment: [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941093/) статья с англоязычного SO, там похожий случай.